# java regex replace all ) but not leading a apostophe

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex that replaces all brackets with a single bracket, but not if an apostrophe is leading the bracket

Examples

```
a) ))) --> expected )
b) )))))) --> expected )
c) '))) --> expected ))
```

Would anybody please help?
I tried `replaceAll("[^']\\)\\)+", ")");`
but unfortunately this is not working.

Comment: Would `')')))` result in `)))`, or is it not a valid input?

Comment: What is the rule when there's an apostrophe? Remove the adjacent parenthesis and leave all others? Or reduce everything to two parentheses?

Answer (score 3):

For your example data, you could match `')` and capture in a group one or more `)`.

Then replace with a single `)`

[`'\)|(\)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/onDeli/1)

As per recommendation from [@ctwheels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3600709/ctwheels) (Thanks for that!) this can be shortened to:

[`'\)|\)+`](https://regex101.com/r/ytwEj4/1)

**Explanation**

This will use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either `')` or multiple times `)`

When this matches, you can replace it with a single `)`

Comment: More elegant than the one I just deleted. Can be shortened to `'\)|\)+` replacement `)` - no need to capture.

Comment: @ctwheels I have updated my answer and included your recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

Use one regex to remove extra parentheses:

```
replaceAll("(?<!')\\)+", ")")
```

And another one to get rid of the quotes `'`:

```
replaceAll("'\\)", ")")
```

Putting this together:

```
System.out.println("')'))))".replaceAll("(?<!')\\)+", ")").replaceAll("'\\)", ")"));
```

Prints `)))`.

Try it online [here](https://ideone.com/XxtlGU).

Comment: Can be condensed into one regex instead of two separate calls. I just deleted my answer that resembles this though because the fourth bird's answer is the same, but shorter and performs better.

Comment: @ctwheels I elected to use two calls for readability, but The fourth bird's answer's simplicity is hard to match.

Answer (score 0):

Try regex:

```
(?<!(\'))\)+

replaceAll("(?<!(\\'))\\)+", ")");
```